# Slow counting record from MYSQL query with looping INNERJOIN

Tags: performance, count, query-optimization, inner-join

Help,
I just want to known count(*) from my database, 
yess i have many to many relation table 
with 100.000 - 150.000 record
so i use INNER JOIN, it's look like workin for me..

BUT....

I have a **very slow** query like this, it's work about 2-5second

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM monitoring_pasien 
INNER JOIN master_desa ON master_desa.DESA_ID = monitoring_pasien.DESA_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_loket ON monitoring_pasien.PASIEN_ID = monitoring_loket.PASIEN_ID AND monitoring_pasien.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_pelayanan ON monitoring_pelayanan.LOKET_ID = monitoring_loket.LOKET_ID AND monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_diagnosa ON monitoring_diagnosa.PELAYANAN_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PELAYANAN_ID AND monitoring_diagnosa.PKM_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN master_penyakit ON master_penyakit.PENYAKIT_ID = monitoring_diagnosa.PENYAKIT_ID
WHERE monitoring_pasien.DESA_ID < 19 AND master_desa.DESA_ID <> 0 AND master_penyakit.SURVEYLANS = '1';
```

And then... 
when i used it with this query, it will wok about 100second :(

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM master_desa WHERE DESA_ID < 19 AND DESA_ID <> 0 ORDER BY DESA asc";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error');
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$DESA = $data["DESA"];
$DESA_ID = $data["DESA_ID"];   

$queryPasien = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS jumPasien FROM monitoring_pasien
INNER JOIN master_desa ON master_desa.DESA_ID = monitoring_pasien.DESA_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_loket ON monitoring_pasien.PASIEN_ID = monitoring_loket.PASIEN_ID AND monitoring_pasien.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_pelayanan ON monitoring_pelayanan.LOKET_ID = monitoring_loket.LOKET_ID AND monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN monitoring_diagnosa ON monitoring_diagnosa.PELAYANAN_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PELAYANAN_ID AND monitoring_diagnosa.PKM_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID
INNER JOIN master_penyakit ON master_penyakit.PENYAKIT_ID = monitoring_diagnosa.PENYAKIT_ID

WHERE master_desa.DESA='$DESA' AND master_penyakit.PENYAKIT_ID = '$penyakit' AND TGL LIKE '$pilihan' ";

$resultPasien = mysql_query($queryPasien) or die('Error');
while($dataPasien = mysql_fetch_array($resultPasien))
{
$jumPasien = $dataPasien['jumPasien'];      

if ($jumData == 0) { $persen = "0%"; } 
else { 
        $bagi = $jumPasien/$jumData;
        $persen = round((float)$bagi * 100 ) . '%';         
     }

echo "<tr>
        <td>$DESA</td>
        <td width=\"40\"> : $persen</td>
        <td width=\"70\">";

$loop = floor($persen/2);
$gambar = "images/bar.png";

for($j=0;$j<=$loop;$j++)
    {
        echo "<img src=\"$gambar\" alt=\"=\" />";
    }       


echo  "</td></tr>";

}

if ($persen >= 0 AND $persen <= 25) { $color = "green"; } 
else if ($persen > 25 AND $persen <= 50) { $color = "blue"; } 
else if ($persen > 50 AND $persen <= 75) { $color = "yellow"; } 
else if ($persen > 75 AND $persen <= 100) { $color = "red"; } 

if ($DESA == 'GEDONGAN') { $gedongan_jml=" $jumPasien Penderita [ $persen ]"; $gedongan_color=$color;}
else if ($DESA == 'BALONGSARI') { $balongsari_jml=" $jumPasien Penderita [ $persen ]"; $balongsari_color=$color;}
else if ($DESA == 'BLOOTO') { $blooto_jml=" $jumPasien Penderita [ $persen ]"; $blooto_color=$color;}
```

}

whats wrong with my code?

Thank's for your help

Comment: Talking about speed isn't constructive without knowing how many rows are in in every single tables. however you're using `LIKE` in your `WHERE` clause - afaik this is very slow.

Comment: Yes, You are correct,
i drop LIKE and using = in WHERE
that's make faster 200%

But still slow, it's 50-70second now

but, so Thanks, that's very helping me

Answer (score 0):

If you have no reason for `INNER JOIN` use `LEFT JOIN` in stead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM monitoring_pasien 
    LEFT JOIN master_desa ON master_desa.DESA_ID = monitoring_pasien.DESA_ID
    LEFT JOIN monitoring_loket ON monitoring_pasien.PASIEN_ID = monitoring_loket.PASIEN_ID AND monitoring_pasien.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
    LEFT JOIN monitoring_pelayanan ON monitoring_pelayanan.LOKET_ID = monitoring_loket.LOKET_ID AND monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID = monitoring_loket.PKM_ID
    LEFT JOIN monitoring_diagnosa ON monitoring_diagnosa.PELAYANAN_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PELAYANAN_ID AND monitoring_diagnosa.PKM_ID = monitoring_pelayanan.PKM_ID
    LEFT JOIN master_penyakit ON master_penyakit.PENYAKIT_ID = monitoring_diagnosa.PENYAKIT_ID
WHERE monitoring_pasien.DESA_ID < 19 AND master_desa.DESA_ID <> 0 AND master_penyakit.SURVEYLANS = '1';
```

Comment: are sure? because in my case, INNER JOIN working faster than LEFT JOIN (tested by navicat)

Comment: it depends on what you want to count and how many entries you have in each table